# XKB layout, remaping key LSGT is disabling the less key

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb, setxkbmap

I am creating a custom XKB layout.
My european keyboard has a physical less/greater key which I want to be mapped as 3rd level modifier.
I used sucesfully `include level3(lsgt_switch)`

However this also have the unwanted side effect of disabling my comma symbol, whose line is:

```
    key <AB08> { [   comma,       less,        ograve,    Ograve ] };
```

I also found out that any line having the `less` symbol get disabled.
Any idea how to get around this issue ?

Full layout:

```
default
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "maximekey" 
{

        name[Group1] = "Maximekey";

        key <AB01> { [              y,                 Y,               agrave,               Agrave ] };
        key <AB02> { [              x,                 X,               aacute,               Aacute ] };
        key <AB03> { [              c,                 C,             ccedilla,             Ccedilla ] };
        key <AB04> { [              v,                 V,               igrave,               Igrave ] };
        key <AB05> { [              b,                 B,               iacute,               Iacute ] };
        key <AB06> { [              n,                 N,               ntilde,               Ntilde ] };
        key <AB07> { [              m,                 M,           dead_greek,            Multi_key ] };
        key <AB08> { [          comma,              less,               ograve,               Ograve ] }; // LINE ALPHA
        key <AB09> { [         period,           greater,               oacute,               Oacute ] };
        key <AB10> { [          slash,          question,         questiondown,            0x1002026 ] };
        key <AC01> { [              a,                 A,           adiaeresis,           Adiaeresis ] };
        key <AC02> { [              s,                 S,               ssharp,              section ] };
        key <AC03> { [              d,                 D,              dstroke,              Dstroke ] };
        key <AC04> { [              f,                 F,               egrave,               Egrave ] };
        key <AC05> { [              g,                 G,               eacute,               Eacute ] };
        key <AC06> { [              h,                 H,               ugrave,               Ugrave ] };
        key <AC07> { [              j,                 J,               uacute,               Uacute ] };
        key <AC08> { [              k,                 K,                U0133,                U0132 ] };
        key <AC09> { [              l,                 L,               oslash,               Oslash ] };
        key <AC10> { [      semicolon,             colon,               eacute,       periodcentered ] };
        key <AC11> { [     apostrophe,          quotedbl,               agrave,        dead_diaeresis] };
        key <AD01> { [              q,                 Q,                   ae,                   AE ] };
        key <AD02> { [              w,                 W,                aring,                Aring ] };
        key <AD03> { [              e,                 E,           ediaeresis,           Ediaeresis ] };
        key <AD04> { [              r,                 R,               yacute,               Yacute ] };
        key <AD05> { [              t,                 T,                thorn,                Thorn ] };
        key <AD06> { [              z,                 Z,           ydiaeresis,           Ydiaeresis ] };
        key <AD07> { [              u,                 U,           udiaeresis,           Udiaeresis ] };
        key <AD08> { [              i,                 I,           idiaeresis,           Idiaeresis ] };
        key <AD09> { [              o,                 O,           odiaeresis,           Odiaeresis ] };
        key <AD10> { [              p,                 P,                   oe,                   OE ] };
        key <AD11> { [    bracketleft,         braceleft,               egrave,                U2039 ] };
        key <AD12> { [   bracketright,        braceright,       guillemotright,                U203A ] };
        key <AE01> { [              1,            exclam,           exclamdown,          onesuperior ] };
        key <AE02> { [              2,                at,          ordfeminine,          twosuperior ] };
        key <AE03> { [              3,        numbersign,            masculine,        threesuperior ] };
        key <AE04> { [              4,            dollar,             EuroSign,                  yen ] };
        key <AE05> { [              5,           percent,             sterling,                 cent ] };
        key <AE06> { [              6,       asciicircum,      dead_circumflex,           dead_caron ] };
        key <AE07> { [              7,         ampersand,       dead_abovering,          dead_macron ] };
        key <AE08> { [              8,          asterisk,   doublelowquotemark,   singlelowquotemark ] };
        key <AE09> { [              9,         parenleft,  leftdoublequotemark,  leftsinglequotemark ] };
        key <AE10> { [              0,        parenright, rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ] };
        key <AE11> { [          minus,        underscore,            copyright,           numerosign ] };
        key <AE12> { [          equal,              plus,             multiply,             division ] };
        key <BKSL> { [      backslash,               bar,              notsign,            brokenbar ] };
        key <TLDE> { [          grave,        asciitilde,           dead_grave,           dead_tilde ] };
        include "level3(ralt_switch)"
        include "level3(lsgt_switch)"  // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// LINE BETA
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a gnome keyboard shortcut messing with it (gnome settings: keyboards shortcuts).
Solved after removing it.

Debug process:
I realized the `<` was still recognised by the gnome shortcut interface (when trying to create a new one). Due a bug in gnome interface, the `<`  wasn't shown in the main menu recensing all the shortcut, and I has to check each shortcut individually to find the culprit.

Comment: It would be good to share your debug process, so future readers will know how to found those guilty shortcuts.